# limit the output to two decimal places

Tags: fortran90

Question1: Why I cant put x=-0.6 inside my do while loop?

```
x=-0.6

do while (x<0.6)
  x = x + 0.1
  write(*,*) x
end do
```

result

```
 -0.40000001    
 -0.30000001      
 -0.20000002      
 -0.10000002          
 -1.49011612E-08  
  9.99999866E-02      
  0.19999999          
  0.29999998         
  0.39999998         
  0.49999997         
  0.59999996
```

But I only want -0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1......0.5, how can I make this please? By declaring `real(kind=2) :: x`. But what is the command in fortran 90?

Comment: Answer to question 1: Because that's how the language works. I don't get what you mean by the declaration `real(kind=2) :: x`, how is it relevant?

Comment: required reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to change the data type, you just want to change the output format:

```
write(*, '(f5.2)') x
```

Comment: `5` is the field width and `2` is the number of decimal places, tweak them to get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks.Is it possible to initialize  x = -0.5 ,exactly -0.5?

Comment: You're having issues with rounding here. I would instead loop an integer from -5 to 5 and multiply by 0.1.